# How to set tracking on an existing repo to a remote repo with ngit (or jgit)?

Tags: branch, tracking, jgit

I am working on a gui based helper utility that will:

- Init a local repo, Init (bare) a remote repo
- Add .gitignore based on a project type
- Commit all the files locally
- Add a remote repo to the local config
- Push master to the remote repo
- Create a develop branch and push it to master

All this is done without git installed by using ngit (.NET port of jgit).

But I can't figure out how to setup tracking to track master to origin/master and develop to origin/develop *using just ngit*.

I can do it easily with

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

However, I was hoping to avoid the dependency of a local git install.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a Java snippet that corresponds to the `--set-upstream` option to `git branch`:

```java
Git git = Git.open(new File("/home/repos/myrepo"));
CreateBranchCommand create = git.branchCreate();
create.setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM);
create.setName("develop");
create.setStartPoint("origin/develop");
create.call();
```

Comment: Beware that you also need to have `.setForce(true)` if the branch already exists locally and you only need to track it remotely.